# Wubi won't start

Tags: installation, wubi

Trying to install Ubuntu on old XP computer. It won't boot from CD and when I open CD it won't run Wubi because it isn't a valid Win32 application.
CD works ok on Win7 and Vista machines. Do I  need a different download? Have Ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

Answer (score 0):

Run `wubi.exe` as the adminitrator, when Windows asks for verification, click "Run".

[image]

Comment: bodhi.zazen   Thanks for reply. Can't even get to administrator stage as it says Wubi isn't a valid Win32 prog.

Comment: Don't know. But disc was ok on other machines. Just won't boot or run Wubi on the old Xp PC. Where I really want it.